# In Django Template how to get all grand child object using single object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a models like :

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Sell(models.Model):
    invoice = models.OneToOneField(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class SellItems(models.Model):
    sell = models.ForeignKey(
        Sell, related_name='sell_item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In template, how can I get `SellItems` using `Invoice` object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following snippet:

```
from models import Invoice
invoice = Invoice.objects.all().first()
if invoice and invoice.sell:
  sell_items = invoice.sell.sell_item.all()
```

Just remember, that `sell` could be none if there is no relation.

Answer (score 0):

to access reverse foreign key relationship, use `_set` from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)

your query:

```
invoice = Invoice.objects.first()
```

in your template:

```
{% for sell in invoice.sell_set.all %}
    <h1>{{ sell.pk }}</h1>
    {% for sell_item in sell.sellitems_set.all %}
        <h1>{{ sell_item.item }}</h1>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```